# Can you pass a value from one fortran program to another fortran program?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I have a program that has a value in a variable.  Once the value is established, I want to call another program and use the value of the variable to determine where to go in the new program.  Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: If you can make the second program a subroutine, you can call it from the first program and exchange information through arguments. Otherwise, follow Mark's instructions.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this method first and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a Fortran 2008 compiler you'll have the standard subroutine `execute_command_line`.  This takes, *inter alia*, a string argument representing the command to execute (along with any arguments for the command) so you could quite easily execute another Fortran program which reads a command-line argument.  That, called, program could use the Fortran 2003 subroutine `get_command_argument` for processing the command line

Even if your compiler is not (fully) Fortran 2008 compliant you may find that it either implements this intrinsic routine, or provides a (non-standard) alternative.  Your compiler documentation will enlighten you.

Comment: We are using a fortran90 compiler...not sure how that measures up?

Comment: If your compiler does not support `execute_command_line`, you can try with the non-standard `system` subroutine as in `call system('myOtherFortranProgram')`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about fortran. But I'd do it via command line arguments. Can't think of a language that doesn't accept them. And as long as it's all input and no output it should suffice. Plus, you can have simple test runs on the program that accepts the input, because you can simply start it with test input from a command shell.

The downside is, that you have to convert your data to strings and parse it in the other program. That's not so much of an issue for simple types but it can be nasty for complex data.

For complex data you can write to a file, provide the file path via command line argument and read the file in the other program. The file based approach also enables the other program to return feedback in the same file.

Here is a SO thread on command lines in fortran:
[Fortran: `READ(*,*)` != Command-line arguments. How to use command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843772/fortran-read-command-line-arguments-how-to-use-command-line-argument)

**Edit:**
I reworded the output part from "print your data as a string" to "convert your data to strings". That part together with the link implied the proposal of printing the data to the screen and reading it from there in the other program. Although this might also be a solution, it was not intended.

Comment: I have the result from the first program writing to the screen.  I can see that this is working.  The second program needs to read that result from the screen, but it is not reading it.  I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but it seems like it should work.  BTW, I am using an AIX editor.

Comment: Reading from the screen is not what I meant. I proposed the same solution as High Performance Mark, but 4 minutes earlier with less detail. Since Mark could list the Fortran commands I added a link to guide you how to use them. The linked SO thread shows the usage of `get_command_argument`. For more information you should google "execute_command_line Fortran".