# Passing Variables from a Shell-Script to a Fortran 90 Program

Tags: bash, fortran, command-line-arguments, fortran90

I'm stuck on this little problem. I was wondering if it is possible to pass a variable of a bash-shell script to a f90 code?

Comment: Wonder no more, it certainly is possible.

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure it was discussed here before, but I cannot find an exact duplicate.

You can pass arguments directly as arguments to the program

```
  ./program arg1 arg2
```

you can retrieve the values in the program as character strings in Fortran 2003 using subroutines [`GET_COMMAND ARGUMENT`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT.html#GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT) and [`COMMAND_ARGUMENT_COUNT`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/COMMAND_005fARGUMENT_005fCOUNT.html#COMMAND_005fARGUMENT_005fCOUNT). Click on the links to get useful examples.

In older Fortran you have to use non-standard extensions, such as the subroutines [`GETARG`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GETARG.html#GETARG) and [`IARGC`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IARGC.html#IARGC).

You can also read an environment variable which was set in the script

```
VAR1 = ...
VAR2 = ...
./program
```

using Fortran 2003 subroutine [`GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fENVIRONMENT_005fVARIABLE.html#GET_005fENVIRONMENT_005fVARIABLE). In older Fortran you have to use some non-standard extension, such as the subroutine [`GETENV`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GETENV.html).

You can also redirect a file to the standard input of the program and read the data using the `READ` statement.

Comment: Yes, this has been discussed many times here on SO.  Even one of my own modest contributions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843772/fortran-read-command-line-arguments-how-to-use-command-line-argument/13844047#13844047) touches on how to read command line arguments with `get_command_argument`.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose between the following possibilities:

- In bash use export of the variable
  `myvar="example"; export myvar`
- Add them as argument to the fortran call
  `myFortran "${myvar}"`
- Write them to a file and read the file
  Worst solution, just to mention them all
- Write it to stdin of fortran program
  `echo "${myvar}" | myFortran`

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning how to get that value in the Fortran program. Actually in strictly standard Fortran 90 the  1 and 2 are not possible, although there are on-standard extensions for that.

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks for adding thr Fortran details.

Comment: The export in combination with getenv worked for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

And you can use the following procedures to read an environment variable: get_environment_variable

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fENVIRONMENT_005fVARIABLE.html

Or read the number and value of the command argument: command_argument_count,get_command_argument. See:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Intrinsic-Procedures.html#Intrinsic-Procedures