# How to define path for input file and out file

Tags: fortran

How to define input path and output path (Both are different location) and input file name and output file name will be same?

I want to add input and output directory to take and save input and output on respective directory but input and output file name will be same.

Simply, I want to make modification of my code to take input files from input directory folder and save output on output directory folder.

Now my code is working but at a time only one file taking, I want to run my same code for multiple files.

Source:

```
        IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
c
c       iaa: residue name
c       iat: atom name
        CHARACTER iaa*4,iat*4,chain*1
        DIMENSION iaa(199),iat(199),chain(199)
c
c       xpr,ypr,zpr: orthogonal coordinates
c       irn: residue number
        DIMENSION xpr(199),ypr(199),zpr(199),irn(199),taa(5)
c
c       set pi value and rad to deg conversion factor
        pi = 0.4D+01*DATAN(0.1D+01)
        rad2deg = 0.18D+03/pi
        deg2rad = pi/0.18D+03
c
        fprec = 2.0*(sin(36.0*deg2rad)+sin(72.0*deg2rad))
c
c       open the input file
        OPEN (1,FILE="1e3i_A.txt")
c
c       read the xyzs, atom and res name and res #
        i = 1
 396    READ (1,500,END=398) iat(i),iaa(i),chain(i),irn(i),xpr(i),
     1                       ypr(i),zpr(i)
c       WRITE(*,500) iat(i),iaa(i),chain(i),irn(i),xpr(i),ypr(i),zpr(i)
        i = i+1
c
c       ensure arrays do not overflow
        IF (i .GT. 199) THEN
          WRITE(*,618)
          STOP
        ENDIF
c
c       loop back and read the next atom entry
        GO TO 396
c
c       set the number of atoms, nat; close input file
 398    nat = i-1
        IF (nat .NE. 40) THEN
          WRITE(*,632) nat
          STOP
        ENDIF
        CLOSE(1)
c
c       open output file
        OPEN (3,FILE="output.dat")
c
c       loop over all atoms; first get B of A-B-C-D

c
c       irt = count of ring torsion angles
        irt = 0
        DO 716 i1 = 1,nat,4
          j1 = i1
          j2 = i1+1
          j3 = i1+2
          j4 = i1+3
c
c         calculate the relevant vectors: j1-j2, j2-j3, j3-j4
          d11 = xpr(j2) - xpr(j1)
          d12 = ypr(j2) - ypr(j1)
          d13 = zpr(j2) - zpr(j1)
          d21 = xpr(j3) - xpr(j2)
          d22 = ypr(j3) - ypr(j2)
          d23 = zpr(j3) - zpr(j2)
          d31 = xpr(j4) - xpr(j3)
          d32 = ypr(j4) - ypr(j3)
          d33 = zpr(j4) - zpr(j3)
c
c         normals to j1-j2-j3 AND j2-j3-j4
c         cross product of j1-j2 and j2-j3 AND of j2-j3 and j3-j4
          p1 = d12*d23 - d13*d22
          p2 = d13*d21 - d11*d23
          p3 = d11*d22 - d12*d21
          q1 = d22*d33 - d23*d32
          q2 = d23*d31 - d21*d33
          q3 = d21*d32 - d22*d31
c
c         calculate cos-of-TA: angle between vectos p and q
          ta = (p1*q1+p2*q2+p3*q3)/(dsqrt(p1*p1+p2*p2+p3*p3)*
     1         dsqrt(q1*q1+q2*q2+q3*q3))
          IF (DABS(ta) .GT. 1.0) ta = 1.0
c
c         calculate magnitude of TA and convert to degrees
c         ta = DACOS(ta)*rad2deg
          ta = DACOS(ta)
c
c         find sign of TA: find cross product of p and q
          x1 = p2*q3 - p3*q2
          y1 = p3*q1 - p1*q3
          z1 = p1*q2 - p2*q1
c
c         if not a null vector, find if parallel to j2-j3 or antiparallel
          IF (DABS(x1)+DABS(y1)+DABS(z1) .NE. 0.0) THEN
            xx = x1*d21 + y1*d22 + z1*d23
            IF (xx .LT. 0.0) ta = -ta
          ENDIF
          irt = irt+1
          taa(irt) = ta
          IF (irt .EQ. 5) THEN
            fnum = taa(5)+taa(2)-taa(4)-taa(1)
            fden = fprec*taa(3)
            tanp = fnum/fden
            phase = DATAN(tanp)*rad2deg
            IF (taa(3) .LT. 0) phase = phase+180.0
            IF (phase .LT. 0) phase = phase+360.0
            WRITE(*,624) phase
            irt = 0
          ENDIF
c
c         output the value
c         WRITE(3,606) iat(j1),irn(j1),iat(j2),irn(j2),iat(j3),
c    2                 irn(j3),iat(j4),irn(j4),ta
 716    CONTINUE
c
c       close output file and exit
        CLOSE(3)
c       WRITE(*,620)
c
        STOP
 500    FORMAT(13X,2A4,A1,I4,4X,3F8.3)
 502    FORMAT(A20)
 606    FORMAT(1X,A4,I4,'... ',A4,I4,'... ',A4,I4,'... ',A4,I4,F12.3)
 618    FORMAT(/' ERROR: number of atoms > 199'/)
 620    FORMAT(/' Bye...Bye....'/)
 622    FORMAT(/' Input: number of atoms ',I4,
     3          ' is not a multiple of 4'/)
 624    FORMAT(F12.3)
 632    FORMAT(/' No. of atoms is',I4,' but expected only 40'/)
        END
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Is the output wrong? Any error messages?

Comment: @VladimirF  There is no error.. I want to add input and output directory.. can you plz suggest ?

Comment: I will not touch any code that begins with `IMPLICIT` other than `IMPLICIT NONE`

Comment: @Vladimir F, can you suggest something?

Comment: Yes, I suggest to explain more clearly what you want to do.

Comment: @Vladimir F, I want to modify code: to put input directory to take input file and to save output file in deferent folder. Simply I want to give path for input and output. I have 2k input files.

Comment: In which way you want to define it. Constant? From a file? From keyboard? From command line parameters? Please be specific. Try to use simple English and describe what you want to do in steps.

Comment: @Vladimir F, from a file. I have multiple input file and want to run above program for all input files and save all output in separate folder. if input file:`1ahi_A.txt`, so output file will be save same file name but deferent folder.

Comment: But which folder!!!!

Comment: If I have two folders: A and B, In A folder we have all input files and we want to save all output file in B folder.

Comment: So why you cannot use file=" B/output.dat" ? Edit your question and explain **in steps** what you want to do.

Comment: @Vladimir F, I want to modify my code to take aa files from directory folder and save output in output directory.

Comment: maybe you want to give the file and directory names as command line parameters ?

Comment: @agentp, Yeah but How? I am new

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13844047/1004168